# Any tool similar to TortoiseSVN for Team Foundation Server in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tortoisesvn

Guys is there any tool similar to TortoiseSVN for Team Foundation Server in VS2008. It should have windows explorer extension showing wat files have been modified etc without opening VS2008.

Thanks and Regards,
PV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Team Foundation Server Power Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBD14EEA-781F-45A1-8C46-9F6BA2F68BF0&displaylang=en) includes a shell extension for Windows Explorer that will provide TFS integration into Windows Explorer.

Comment: It Worked Thank you ..Do you know any tool which shows colors on folder which indicates there is a change in the TFS local copy.